# Double-free error in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I do tried to find an answer on the books that I got and search on google but can not find a clue to the root of the problem.

It may be something really stupid. 
Hope someone could shed some light here
I'm copying everything here below:

Hand::ShowHand2 is only working with "myHand.Add(pCard2)"
somehow when I use myHand.Add(pCard1) I got the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/remy/workspace-C/myPoker/Debug/myPoker: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fff7723d2d0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7fef4fd1bb96]
/home/remy/workspace-C/myPoker/Debug/myPoker[0x401869]
/home/remy/workspace-C/myPoker/Debug/myPoker[0x40172c]
/home/remy/workspace-C/myPoker/Debug/myPoker[0x401b41]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fef4fcbe76d]
/home/remy/workspace-C/myPoker/Debug/myPoker[0x400e19]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 875533                             /home/remy/workspace-C/myPoker/Debug/myPoker
00603000-00604000 r--p 00003000 07:00 875533                             /home/remy/workspace-C/myPoker/Debug/myPoker
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 07:00 875533                             /home/remy/workspace-C/myPoker/Debug/myPoker
02534000-02555000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Card
{
public:
    enum rank {ace = 1, two, three, four, five, six , seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king};
    enum suit {club =1 , diamonds, hearts, spades};
    friend ostream& operator    <<  (ostream& os,  Card& aCard);

    Card(rank r = ace, suit s = spades);
    rank m_rank;
    suit m_suit;

};

Card::Card(rank r, suit s){
    m_rank =    r;
    m_suit  =   s;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  Card& aCard)
{
    const string RANKS[] = {"0", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                        "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
    const string SUITS[] = {"c", "d", "h", "s"};
    os << RANKS[aCard.m_rank] << SUITS[aCard.m_suit];

    return os;
}

class Hand
{
    public:
    Hand();
    virtual ~Hand();

void Add(Card* pCard);
void Clear();
void ShowHand();
void ShowHand2();

    protected:
    vector<Card*> m_Cards;

};

Hand::Hand(){
    cout    << "hand is created "   << endl;
    m_Cards.reserve(7);
}
Hand::~Hand()
{
    Clear();
}

void Hand::Add(Card* pCard)
{
    cout    <<  "*pCard: "  <<  *pCard  << " is @: "    <<  pCard   <<  endl;
    m_Cards.push_back(pCard);
}

void Hand::Clear(){
    vector<Card*>::iterator iter = m_Cards.begin();
    for (iter = m_Cards.begin(); iter != m_Cards.end(); ++iter)
    {
    delete *iter;
    *iter   =   0;
    }
    m_Cards.clear();
}


void Hand::ShowHand(){

        int k = 1;
        vector<Card*>::iterator iter = m_Cards.begin();
    for (iter = m_Cards.begin() ; iter != m_Cards.end(); ++iter, ++k)
    {
        cout    << "card no "   <<  k   << " is: ";
        cout    <<  **iter  << endl ;
    }

}


void Hand::ShowHand2(){

        vector<Card*>::iterator iter = m_Cards.begin();
        cout << "this hand has "    <<  m_Cards.size()  << " card(s)."<< endl;

        for (iter = m_Cards.begin(); iter != m_Cards.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout    << **iter   <<  endl;
}
}



int main(){

Card c1(static_cast<Card::rank>(11), static_cast<Card::suit>(0));

Card*   pCard1  =   &c1;
Card*   pCard2;
pCard2  =   new Card(static_cast<Card::rank>(12), static_cast<Card::suit>(0));

Hand myHand;

myHand.Add(pCard1);
//  myHand.Add(pCard2);

//  myHand.ShowHand();
myHand.ShowHand2();

cout    <<  "End of Program"    <<  endl;


return 0;
}
```

Big thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you try to run the program with valgrind's memcheck?

Comment: Try using gdb to debug your code.

Comment: @Griwes: People learning a new language should learn about it from the ground up.  Telling a C++ beginner to "stop using raw pointers" (in a snarky way I may add) is obtuse and counterproductive.

Comment: @EdS., learning smart pointers is far closer to the ground than learning raw pointers and manual memory management.

Comment: @EdS. Smart pointers are a ground of C++.

Comment: @EdS. what. Why? Came you come up with *one* good reason why a beginner should *start out* learning to use language constructs that experienced programmers in that language try to avoid as much as possible? The only reasons to point beginners towards pointers is that (1) you hate beginners and want them to suffer, or (2) you learned C++ wrong, and think others should too

Comment: @jalf: Because it is impossible to appreciate *why* we use smart pointers and container types if you don't first understand the pitfalls of manual memory management.  One cannot understand why a pattern like RAII exists before first running into some of these problems.  Worst of all, they don't understand the semantics of these constructs because they don't understand the problem they are attempting to solve.

Comment: @Griwes: Um, no, it's not.  They are a level of abstraction introduced to solve a problem that experienced programmers understand. This sort of advice is the reason we see far too many programmers working in the industry who can't solve the tough problems when their leaky abstractions fail them.

Comment: @EdS. when people learn to drive, do you start out by pushing the car over a cliff so that they'll appreciate the airbag? Do you start out ramming them with another car in the first intersection you can find, just so they'll appreciate traffic lights?

Comment: @EdS. I suggest you continue this discussion [in the Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec).

Comment: @jalf: False analogy.  I'd also point out that I know C++ better than most having used it daly for some time now, so you can cut the ad hominem nonsense.  It is impossible to understand why an abstraction exists and how to use it properly without first understanding the problem it is trying to solve.

Comment: @EdS. please, go and learn C++ properly, then come back. Smart pointers and RAII are *absolutely* the fundamentals of manual memory management in C++.

Comment: @EdS. I call you to make better abstractions than "leaky" in standard library. I also don't think that making mistakes is essential in learning, because you can simply learn to make things the proper way.

Comment: @EdS. so why is my analogy false? You are arguing that a person needs to be hit full force by a problem in order to understand how to avoid it in the future. I think my analogies matched that pretty well. And, if it is *impossible* to learn the way we are describing, how do you explain that people have actually learned C++ in that way?

Comment: @jalf: Please.  No need to start attacking me because I disagree with you.  You must have a very high opinion of yourself to claim that I don't know C++.  What are you basing that assertion off of?  I have been writing C++ in relatively complex systems for years.  I don't pass around raw pointers to memory I allocated myself unless it is absolutely necessary, which is almost never.  Of course, I *understand* how the language works, so I am able to make informed decisions about the code I write.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: All abstractions are leaky, I didn't say they were poorly designed.

Comment: @EdS., the reason 90% of C++ programmers suck is because they think that manual memory management rules. And because 95% of teachers suck and think that manual memory management rules.

Comment: @EdS. I have a high opinion of a lot of C++ programmers who have realized that the way C++ was taught 20 years ago was horrible. And why are "all abstractiosn leaky"? What do you base that claim upon? How are the *specific* abstractions in question here leaky?

Comment: @jalf: I base it upon using said abstractions for years. Here's something I see from beginners all of the time: `vector<int*> v;` That's one way in which they're leaky.  A beginner doesn't understand that only the memory used *to store the pointer itself* is deallocated when the vector is destroyed. Are you seriously claiming that understanding how memory management works is a *bad* thing?  Really?

Comment: @EdS., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254067/double-free-error-in-c#comment25006374_17254067

Answer (score 3):

You add `pCard1` to your hand, which is a pointer to a local variable that will be destroyed automatically.
However, your `~Hand()` will call `delete` on all cards it has assigned.
There you have your double free.

If you use `pCard2` you allocated the `Card` instance via `new` and are therefore responsible for calling delete on it.

As you can see in the comments you should think about using smart pointers to avoid such problems.

**Edit**
To explain your main problem in more detail:
You use a pointer to a local variable which is automatically managed by the compiler.
However you then `add()` it to the hand which takes ownership of the pointed object in that it will delete it, when the hand itself is destructed.
This basically leads to having two owners for the same object.

By generating an instance via new there is no owner who takes care of the destruction.
However, when you add it to the hand then the hand owns it and will delete it.

Comment: thanks lot @Nobody. actually my 400 pages beginner book did not even mention "smart pointer". I'm googling now...hope c++ is not too smart to slow ppl like me :(

Comment: forgive me to not entirely understand your answer. when exactly `~Hand()` is called ? it's after `myHand.Add(pCard1);` or `myHand.showHand2();` ? or after `return 0;`

Comment: @Remyx: No! pCard1 is a pointer to c1, which in turn is automatically deleted, when it goes out of scope, i.e., when the `return 0;` is reached. The same goes for `~Hand()`. It also will be automatically deleted at `return 0;` and this is where you get your double free. First `~Hand()` is called which deletes its pointer that points to `c1` and then `c1` is deleted again, which triggers the error.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take this:

```
enum suit {club =1 , diamonds, hearts, spades};
```

Here you declare `club` to be `1`, `diamonds` to be `2`,`` `hearts `` to be `3` and `spades` to be `4`.

Then you have this array

```
const string SUITS[] = {"c", "d", "h", "s"};
```

that you index with the `suit`.

However, arrays start their index with *zero*, which means that for a `spade` you index out of bounds of the array, and enter the territory of *undefined behavior* when you use the "string" at `SUITS[4]`.

Comment: thanks @Joachim Pileborg. I now changed the code to : const string SUITS[] = {"0","c", "d", "h", "s"};